# How do you calculate with bytes in python

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python and mostly rely on my knowledge of c++. But I got into python because of the raspberry pi. I got myself some intelligent servos(LX-224), and have a problem reading the angle from the RPI. I know it's possible, but python keeps throwing some errors. Basically, the RPI sends a command to the servo, and the servo returns eight bytes of information. I only really need two of the bytes, with which I then am supposed to preform a ?calculation?. All the comments to the code are in chinese, so I only know what google translator told me. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import serial
import time

serialHandle = serial.Serial("/dev/serial0", 115200, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=1)

command = {"MOVE_WRITE":1, "POS_READ":28, "LOAD_UNLOAD_WRITE": 31}


def servoWriteCmd(id, cmd, par1 = None, par2 = None):
    buf = bytearray(b'\x55\x55')
    try:
        len = 3
        buf1 = bytearray(b'')
        
        if par1 is not None:
            len += 2
            par1 = 0xffff & par1
            buf1.extend([(0xff & par1), (0xff & (par1 >> 8))])
        if par2 is not None:
            len += 2
            par2 = 0xffff & par2
            buf1.extend([(0xff & par2), (0xff & (par2 >> 8))])
    
        buf.extend([(0xff & id), (0xff & len), (0xff & cmd)])
        buf.extend(buf1)
        
        sum = 0x00
        for b in buf:
            sum += b
        sum = sum - 0x55 - 0x55
        sum = ~sum
        buf.append(0xff & sum)
        
        serialHandle.write(buf)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def readPosition(id):
    serialHandle.flushInput()#supposed to flush the buffer
    servoWriteCmd(id, command["POS_READ"])#send the read command to the servo
    time.sleep(0.005)#give some time to the servo to reply
    count = serialHandle.inWaiting()#how many bytes are waiting for me to read
    pos = None

    if count != 0:
        recv_data = serialHandle.read(count)
        if count == 8:
            if recv_data[0] == b'\x55' and recv_data[1] == b'\x55' and recv_data[4] == b'\x1c' :
                #these bytes tell some information about the command recieved I believe, but they come in all right, so this if statement could be ignored I think

                 pos= b'\xff\xff' & (recv_data[5] | (b'\xff\x00' & (recv_data[6] << 8)))
                 #this is the problem
                 
    return pos

                
servoWriteCmd(1, command["LOAD_UNLOAD_WRITE"],0)
while True:
    try:
        pos = readPosition(1)
        print(pos)
        time.sleep(1)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

Python keeps telling me:

> unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'

So I suppose it's converting the bytes recv_data[5] and [6] to string? I am sorry if this doesn't make any sense, but I could't find any information about "byte calculation" in python.

If anyone has experience with reading the intelligent servos, any other code snippets are also appreciated!

Thanks very much, if something is unclear, I will try my best to clarify it.

Comment: In general, you don't do calculations with bytes, but with numbers. There are different ways to interpret bytes as numbers.

Comment: Unlike in C++, there are no `char` datatypes in Python; a single character of a string is just a string of length 1, which is why you can't perform arithmetic on them.

Comment: Heads up that the ``#this is the problem`` comment is very hard to find amongst all the noise. It doesn't even fit into the code window for me and needs scrolling. Posting the full traceback instead of just the error message would solve the need for the comment.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of ``recv_data``? The error message implies it's a ``str`` or list of ``str``. The ``if recv_data[0] == b'\x55'`` implies it's a list of ``bytes``. The docs imply it's plain ``bytes``. Are you using Python2 perhaps?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I am indeed using python2, is that a problem? Also what do You mean by providing a sample? Printing it out in console? Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `&` on `bytes` type you need to convert it to `int`.

For that you can do : `int.from_bytes(your_bytes_value, byteorder='big')`

```
pos= int.from_bytes(b'\xff\xff', byteorder='big') & (recv_data[5] | (int.from_bytes(b'\xff\x00', byteorder='big') & (recv_data[6] << 8)))
```

Comment: "When you index a bytes, you get a bytes of lenght 1." No you don't. You get an ``int``. ``b"A"[0]`` is ``65``.

Comment: yes sorry I miss read the docs. I have updated the answer

Comment: Indeed, but the question code already errors out on ``<<``. It never actually gets to the ``&``.

Answer (score 0):

so apparently the problem was that I was using python 2.7.16 instead of python 3.7.3. Big thank you to @MisterMiyagi for pointing that out. I upgraded to python 3.7.3, and the original code from the seller of the servos started working. Sorry about this beginner mistake. Thank you to all of you who took the time to comment!